# Trouble Solving Partial Differential Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, mathematics, differential-equations, navier-stokes

I'm solving the velocity profile of a fluid flow for a circular channel with an oscillating pressure gradient $\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{\Delta p}{\rho L}e^{-i\omega t}$. I plugged in to the Navier Stokes equations and am having trouble figuring out how to approach the solution to the partial differential equation below for u(r,t).

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}  - \frac{\Delta p}{\rho L} e^{-i\omega t} = \mu\left(\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)u$$

I know if the $\frac{\Delta p}{\rho L} e^{-i\omega t}$ term weren't in the equation, I could use separation of variables, but the addition of that term seems to throw a wrench in things.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Relevant [meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12758/179151) about some previous answers and possible close reason

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with Chet, I think complex numbers are the way to go here.

As ever in these kind of problems, given that we have an oscillating pressure gradient, it makes sense to look for an oscillating  velocity profile,
$$
u(r,t) = \hat{u}(r)e^{-i\omega t}.
$$
Then your PDE reduces to the ODE
$$
r^2\frac{d^2\hat{u}}{dr^2} + r\frac{d\hat{u}}{dr} + \frac{i\omega r^2}{\mu}\hat{u} + \frac{\Delta p r^2}{\rho L\mu} = 0.
$$
Now make the change of variables $\hat{u} = U(r) - \frac{\Delta p}{\rho L i \omega}$ and $x = r\sqrt{\frac{i\omega}{\mu}}$. Denoting derivatives with respect to $x$ with primes, this becomes
$$
x^2U'' + xU' + x^2U=0.
$$
This is [Bessel's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), which has solutions given by Bessel functions.

Comment: Both methods lead to the same results.  I just personally prefer not to complex numbers in such problems.

Comment: Yes, its definitely a personal preference. I've always preferred exponentials to trig.

Comment: That's fine.  But, in this problem (and ones like it), the answer is in terms of trig functions.

Comment: Plus, shouldn't the pressure term in your equation also have an $r^2$?  And, rather than the dynamic viscosity $\mu$, shouldn't this be the kinematic viscosity $\nu$?

Comment: Is there any meaning to the substitution $x=\sqrt{i\omega/\mu}$ in terms of natural units of the problem?

Comment: Good question. The radial length scale is $\sqrt{\mu/\omega}$. As for what the square root I is doing, I'm not sure what the natural interpretation is.

Answer (score 2):

I never use complex numbers on a problem like this.  I would represent u as $$u=A(r)\cos{\omega t}+B(r)\sin{\omega t}\tag{1}$$  This leads to two coupled ODEs in r for A and B.

So I would start with $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}  - \frac{\Delta p}{\rho L} \cos{\omega t} = \nu\left(\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)u\tag{2}$$where $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity.  And substituting Eqn. 1 into this equation, I would obtain:  $$\nu\left[A''+\frac{A'}{r}\right]-\omega B=-\frac{\Delta P}{\rho L}\tag{3}$$and $$\nu\left[B''+\frac{B'}{r}\right]+\omega A=0\tag{4}$$

Comment: So I took your suggestion and plugged in that representation of u and got the following:
$\mu A''(r) + \frac{\mu}{r}A'(r)-\omega B(r) = -\frac{\Delta p}{\rho L}$ 
and 
$mu B'(r) + \frac{\mu}{r}B'(r) + \omega A'(r) = -\frac{\Delta p i}{\rho L}$
I'm not sure how to continue from here as my experience with these kind of ODEs is limited. Would you have any advice as to how to continue? Thanks!

Comment: Only one of the equations should have a pressure term , and the 2nd equation should not have an A’.   Solve the 1st Eqn for B, and substitute into the 1st equation.

Comment: It should be just an A.

Comment: See the extended version of my answer.